# How to use this pseudo a::hover::after in Chakra UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, chakra-ui

I am trying some css styles that requires the use of the pseudo `a::hover::after`, I assumed that as stated in the [documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/style-props#pseudo)
that as I can do this to use the hover pseudo:

```
<Link _hover={{//styles here}}/>
```

In the same sense using `hover::after` should be like this:

```
<Link _hover_after={{//styles here}}/>
```

But it doesn't seem to work, and I can't find a clue about this particular use in the [documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/style-props#pseudo).
How can I use the pseudo `::hover::after` on a React element with Chakra UI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced that problem before and I couldn't find a solution. But I made a workaround using a `isHovering` state so when `onMouseOver` event set it to **true** and `onMouseLeave` you set it to **false** and adding conditional styles. See an example:

```
const LinkElement = () => {
    const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);

    return <Link 
                _after={ color: isHovering ? 'red' : 'blue' } 
                onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovering(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovering(false)}
            />
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!That solved it but I was wondering, will this affect the performance in anyway?

Comment: This shouldn't affect performance in a way it really matters, as it's only a state change, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

Its a bit late, but the suggested solution doesn't work, if you map an array to display your components and it can get unclean, if you use it multiple times. I found a better solution on a github repo. You can simply do

```
<Link 
   _hover={{
      _after: {
         //styles here
      },
}}/>
```